# Sort CSV columns by value

Tags: ruby, sorting, csv

My CSV file looks like

```
Name,Value1,Value2,Value3
bbb,1,3,4
aaa,5,1,7
ccc,2,2,5
```

Is there a way to sort by `Value1` for example?
So that the result would be

> bbb,1,3,4
>   ccc,2,2,5
>   aaa,5,1,7

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found [SmarterCSV](https://github.com/tilo/smarter_csv), so I was able to easily do:

```
array_of_hashes = SmarterCSV.process('file.csv')
array_of_hashes.sort_by! { |hsh| hsh[:value1] }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are storing all the values in an array of arrays or a hash you can use [`Enumerable#sort`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort).

```
sort_index = 1 # or Hash Key "Value1"
values.sort { |a, b| a[sort_index] <=> b[sort_index] }
```

Note: without using the bang `!` this will return the sorted list. If you want it to change it in place use `#sort!`.

Answer (score 0):

**using Raku (formerly known as Perl6)**

```
~$ cat "sort_col2.txt" | raku -e 'my @a = lines(); \
my @b = @a>>.comb(/^^ .*?  \, <(\d+)> \, /).flat; \
my $c = @b.pairs.sort(*.values)>>.keys.flat; \
@a[$c.flat].join("\n").put'
```

OUTPUT:

```
Name,Value1,Value2,Value3
bbb,1,3,4
ccc,2,2,5
aaa,5,1,7
```

HTH.

https://raku.org